# Flatten nested JSON structure in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, object, nested

I'm trying to write a Postgres query that will output my `json` data in a particular format.

**JSON data structure**

```
{
    user_id: 123,
    data: {
        skills: {
            "skill_1": {
                "title": "skill_1",
                "rating": 4,
                "description": 'description text'
            },
            "skill_2": {
                "title": "skill_2",
                "rating": 2,
                "description": 'description text'
            },
            "skill_3": {
                "title": "skill_3",
                "rating": 5,
                "description": 'description text'
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I need the data to be formatted in the end:

```
[
    {
        user_id: 123,
        skill_1: 4, 
        skill_2: 2, 
        skill_3: 5, 
                    ... 
    },
    {
        user_id: 456,
        skill_1: 1, 
        skill_2: 3, 
        skill_3: 4, 
                    ... 
    }
]
```

So far I'm working with a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    data#>>'{skills, "skill_1",  rating}' AS "skill_1",
    data#>>'{skills, "skill_2",  rating}' AS "skill_2",
    data#>>'{skills, "skill_3",  rating}' AS "skill_3"
FROM some_table
```

There has to be a better way to go about writing my query. There are 400+ rows and 70+ skills. My above query is a little crazy. Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

**Some things to note:**

1. Users rated themselves on 70+ skills
2. Each skill object has the same structure
3. Each user rated themselves on the exact same set of skills

Comment: In your data structure I am missing the user_id field.

Comment: Updated: They are on the same level as the data object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e78cc5cfc7259950d5e29ef643b27efb)

I expanded your test data to (note the array around all users):

```
[{
    "user_id": 123,
    "data": {
        "skills": {
            "skill_1": {
                "title": "skill_1",
                "rating": 4,
                "description": "description text"
            },
            "skill_2": {
                "title": "skill_2",
                "rating": 2,
                "description": "description text"
            },
            "skill_3": {
                "title": "skill_3",
                "rating": 5,
                "description": "description text"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "user_id": 456,
    "data": {
        "skills": {
            "skill_1": {
                "title": "skill_1",
                "rating": 1,
                "description": "description text"
            },
            "skill_2": {
                "title": "skill_2",
                "rating": 3,
                "description": "description text"
            },
            "skill_3": {
                "title": "skill_3",
                "rating": 4,
                "description": "description text"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

The query:

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(user_id || skills))               -- E
FROM (
    SELECT
        json_build_object('user_id', user_id)::jsonb as user_id,  -- D
        json_object_agg(skill_title, skills -> skill_title -> 'rating')::jsonb as skills
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            user_id,
            json_object_keys(skills) as skill_title,         -- C
            skills
        FROM (
            SELECT
                (datasets -> 'user_id')::text as user_id,
                datasets -> 'data' -> 'skills' as skills     -- B
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                  json_array_elements(json) as datasets      -- A
                FROM (
                  SELECT '/* the JSON data; see db<>fiddle */'::json
                )s
            )s
        )s  
    )s    
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY user_id
)s
```

A Make all array elements (`{user_id: '42', data: {...}}`) one row each

B First column safe the `user_id`. The cast to text ist necessary for the `GROUP BY` later which cannot group JSON output. For the second column extract the `skills` data of the user

C Extract the skill titles for using them as keys in (D.1).

D.1 `skills -> skill_title -> 'rating'` extracts the rating value from each skill

D.2 `json_object_agg` aggregates the skill_titles and each corresponding rating value into one JSON object; grouped by the `user_id`

D.3 `json_build_object` makes the user_id a JSON object again

E.1 `user_id || skills` aggregates the two json object into one

E.2 `jsonb_agg aggregates` these json objects into an array

E.3 `jsonb_pretty` makes the result looking pretty.

Result:

```
[{
    "skill_1": 4,
    "skill_2": 2,
    "skill_3": 5,
    "user_id": "123"
},
{
    "skill_1": 1,
    "skill_2": 3,
    "skill_3": 4,
    "skill_4": 42,
    "user_id": "456"
}]
```

Comment: This is truly amazing. Should this work in version 9.6.6? I should have added that to my original question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes it works for Postgres 9.6 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/19326 Please don't forget to accept and upvote.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. This is exactly what I needed. You must be a postgres wizard!!! Your magic is very strong.

Comment: :D. Maybe a little bit :) No, fun! It is just about reading the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html and then trial and error until it works.