# Postgres: How to flatten nested json data

Tags: postgresql

New to postgres.  I am trying to flatten this nested json data and following this example ([Flatten nested JSON structure in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850860/flatten-nested-json-structure-in-postgresql)) but I'm stuck.  The result so far seems to be a cross product combination of timestamp and amount that I can't seem to resolve. The data I'm trying to end up with should look like this.

| shard | prefix | id | timestamp | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 12345 | 1703119840677243794 | 11111 |
| 0 | 0 | 12345 | 1703206309696691698 | 22222 |

```
SELECT 
   shard
   , prefix
   , id
   , field
   , value
   --, fields
FROM (
  SELECT 
        shard, prefix, id
        , json_object_keys(json_array_elements(fields)) as field
        , json_each_text(json_array_elements(fields)) as value
        --, fields
  FROM (
    SELECT
        (datasets -> 'shard')::text as shard,
        (datasets -> 'prefix')::text as prefix,
        (datasets -> 'id')::text as id,
        (datasets -> 'amounts' -> 'fields') as fields
            FROM(
                 SELECT 
                    json_array_elements(json) as datasets
                  FROM (
                    SELECT '[
              {
                "amounts": {
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "amount": 11111,
                      "timestamp": "1703119840677243794"
                    },
                    {
                      "amount": 22222,
                      "timestamp": "1703206309696691698"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "shard": 0,
                "prefix": 0,
                "id": 12345
              }
            ]'::json
        )d)c)b)a;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  `json_extract_path` is the key

```
SELECT 
        shard, prefix, id        
        , json_extract_path(json_array_elements(fields), 'amount') AS amount
        , json_extract_path(json_array_elements(fields), 'timestamp') AS timestamp
  FROM (
    SELECT
            (datasets -> 'shard')::text as shard,
            (datasets -> 'prefix')::text as prefix,
        (datasets -> 'id')::text as id,
        (datasets -> 'amounts' -> 'fields') as fields
            FROM(
          SELECT 
                      json_array_elements(json) as datasets
                  FROM (
                    SELECT '[
              {
                "amounts": {
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "amount": 11111,
                      "timestamp": "1703119840677243794"
                    },
                    {
                      "amount": 22222,
                      "timestamp": "1703206309696691698"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "shard": 0,
                "prefix": 0,
                "id": 12345
              }
            ]'::json
        )d)c)b;
```